# Empty characters when reading file edited with script

Tags: php, character, whitespace

I have a simple formatting/writing script going on, but whenever I save it and read it (writing it inside a `<textarea>` HTML tag), I get some strange empty characters, like when you press Tab in a text editor, both before and after the actual text. If I open the wrote file with a text editor, there's only the text. Here's my script (relevant code only):

```
<?php 
$text = $_POST["info"];
$text = str_replace("\n", "<br />", $text);
$text = preg_replace('/\*([^\*]+)\*/', '<b>\1</b>', $text);
if ($_POST["updateContato"]="updateContato") {
    $file = fopen("./pages/contato.php","w");
    fwrite($file, $text);
    fclose($file);
}
?>
<form action="./?painel" method="post">
    <textarea name="info" class="fullwidth">
    <?php include "./pages/contato.php";?>
    </textarea> <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="updateContato" value="updateContato" checked style="display:none;height:0;width:0;" />
    <input type="submit" value="Salvar" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using this code to render content of `<textarea>` you should **place it in between opening and closing tag without any tabs, new lines or spaces between content and tags**!

```
<form action="./?painel" method="post">
    <textarea name="info" class="fullwidth"><?php include "./pages/contato.php";?></textarea> <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="updateContato" value="updateContato" checked style="display:none;height:0;width:0;" />
    <input type="submit" value="Salvar" />
</form>
```

**On other note**, do you use `return` keyword to return the contents from `"./pages/contato.php"`?

Cause if you don't, `include "..."` is not a good option to use to return a textual data.
Rather save your data into regular file (in non public folder) and instead of including it, read it with `file_get_contents()`:

```
<form action="./?painel" method="post">
    <textarea name="info" class="fullwidth"><?php echo file_get_contents("./pages/contato.php"); ?></textarea> <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="updateContato" value="updateContato" checked style="display:none;height:0;width:0;" />
    <input type="submit" value="Salvar" />
</form>
```

**On one other note**, calling `include "some_script.php"` will actually **execute the script** and if you write things into the script like in your example, **there is a strong possibility of code/parse error and poses a serious security risks if you present this functionality to public or your customers** (or even using it yourself for that matter). Even if you use the return in called script it is still significant security hole.

I strongly recommend you use `file_get_contents()` instead!